# Handling */* content-type in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring

I am using Spring Controller to handle some requests. I am getting above exception. I have handled `application/json`, `application/xml`, etc. But I am not sure about `*/*` and how it should handle in controller. Here is my controller code.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/handle", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody Response handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestBody TestDTO testDTO, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) throws Exception {
}
```

Here is the exception:

```
Unexpected error: Content type '*/*;charset=UTF-8' not supported
org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type '*/*;charset=UTF-8' not supported
```

Please let me know I am missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the final solution that worked for me. Removed `@RequestBody` and added `consumes` - `MediaType.All_VALUE`. Here is the code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/notify", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = {MediaType.ALL_VALUE})
    public @ResponseBody Response notifyPaymentPost(HttpServletRequest request, PaymentDTO paymentDTO, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) throws Exception {
}
```

Comment: What is the use of removing `@ResponseBody` here?

Comment: Actually you should not do that. You would also accept `text/plain` and the app would be open to CSRF attacks. You should specify which types you accept in braces.